# Using a shortcode to construct and execute another shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to know how to execute a shortcode that's created *inside* of another shortcode. Everything I've searched for on this topic has involved nesting one shortcode in another, e.g.:`[myshortcode][anothershortcode][/myshortcode]`, which is **not** what I'm talking about.

My code:

```
function cp_edit_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
        'label' => '',
    ), $atts );
    if ($a['id'] && $a['label']){
        $sc1 = '[' . $a['id'] . ']';
        $sc2 = '[editlink label="✎" prefix="frm_cell_' . $a['label'] . '_" fields="' . $a['id'] . '"]';
        $output = '<span id="frm_cell_' . $a['label'] . '_[id]">' . $sc1 . '</span> ' . $sc2;
        return do_shortcode($output);
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'cp-edit', 'cp_edit_shortcode' );
```

When I do `[cp-edit id="127" label="tycard"]`, this returns `[127] [editlink label="✎" prefix="frm_cell_tycard_" fields="127"]`. It's perfect, except I want it to execute the shortcodes instead of just displaying the HTML. When I paste those shortcodes directly, they execute properly.

Also, I know `[127]` doesn't seem like a proper shortcode. This is actually taking place in the context of a form building plugin in a view that's displaying form entries, so these shortcodes are actually getting executed in the context of that plugin's shortcode. I suspect the problem is I don't comprehensively understand the order that the shortcodes are being executed in. Is it possible for me to have a custom shortcode like this, that outputs shortcodes that are then executed within the plugin's shortcode?

---

**EDIT:** I did some more testing. I tried constructing another shortcode that *wasn't* reliant upon being inside the plugin's shortcode, and that one worked. Both `[127]` and `[editlink ...]` only execute when they're in the plugin's view-building tool (which is then called via a shortcode). A better version of my question is: is there a way to make my custom shortcode execute first, returning those two shortcodes, and have the containing shortcode execute those normally?

Comment: briefly looking... try `echo do_shortcode($output)` instead of returning it

Comment: Using `echo` still doesn't execute shortcodes, and it causes the text to display at the top of the page instead of in the correct place on the page.